# Sqlite3 calculate the percentages from totals

Tags: database, sqlite, dataset

Question(*):
The total number of cases and deaths as a percentage of the population, for each country (with country, % cases of population, % deaths of population as columns)

I have two tables :
countriesAffected(countriesAndTerritories,geoId,countryterritoryCode,popData2019,continentExp)

victimsCases(dateRep,cases,deaths,geoId)

where primary key(geoid)

I tried to do (*) by this method:

```
SELECT countriesAndTerritories, (100 *SUM(victimsCases.cases) / popData2019)as "cases" ,(100 * SUM(deaths) / popData2019) as "deaths"
FROM countriesAffected 
INNER JOIN victimsCases ON victimsCases.geoId = countriesAffected.geoId
GROUP BY countriesAndTerritories
ORDER BY countriesAndTerritories DESC;
```

Error: near line 2: near "SELECT countriesAndTerritories": syntax error

But for some reason I get all types of syntax errors, i tried to sort it out but with no results. And not sure where did i went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error `Error: near line 2: near "SELECT countriesAndTerritories": syntax error` then **the issue is with LINE 1** (perhaps no `;` at the end of line 1).

Otherwise your query works albiet probably not as intended (as you may well want decimal places for the percentages).

Consider the following (that shows your SQL with additional SQL added to work as intended (see casesV2 and deathsV2 that utilise CAST to force INTEGER to REAL)).

```
DROP TABLE If EXISTS victimsCases;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS countriesAffected;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS countriesAffected (countriesAndTerritories TEXT,geoId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,countryterritoryCode TEXT,popData2019 INTEGER,continentExp TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS victimsCases (dateRep TEXT,cases INTEGER ,deaths INTEGER,geoId INTEGER);

INSERT INTO countriesAffected VALUES 
    ('X',1,'XXX',10000,'?'),('Y',2,'YYY',20000,'?'),('Z',3,'ZZZ',30000,'?')
;
INSERT INTO victimsCases VALUES 
    ('2019-01-01',100,20,1),('2019-01-02',100,25,1),('2019-01-03',100,15,1),
    ('2019-01-01',30,5,2),('2019-01-02',33,2,2),
    ('2019-01-01',45,17,3),('2019-01-02',61,4,3),('2019-01-03',75,7,3)
;
    
SELECT countriesAndTerritories,
    (100 *SUM(victimsCases.cases) / popData2019)as "cases", /* ORIGINAL */
    (100 * SUM(deaths) / popData2019) as "deaths", /* ORIGINAL */
    CAST(SUM(victimsCases.cases) AS FLOAT) / popData2019 * 100 AS "casesV2",
    CAST(SUM(victimscases.deaths) AS FLOAT) / popData2019 * 100 as "deathsV2"
FROM countriesAffected 
INNER JOIN victimsCases ON victimsCases.geoId = countriesAffected.geoId
GROUP BY countriesAndTerritories
ORDER BY countriesAndTerritories DESC;

DROP TABLE If EXISTS victimsCases;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS countriesAffected;
```

The result of the above is :-

[image]